# What is the definition of "creative press"?

Tags: word-meaning

What is it supposed to mean in this context?

> During analysis of creativity, the following four themes emerged:
>   Production, creative process, creative press and creative person.

Consulting [this dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/press_1), didn't find any heplful meaning which would fit to this context.

Comment: Where did this sentence appear? Please link to the specific publication, or provide its name and description (and if possible, include a preceding and following sentence or two). Such language sounds like it comes either from an academic paper or from a business analyst, which is to say it is likely to be at once jargon specific to their domain or discipline, and gibberish.

Comment: See https://books.google.com/books?id=JWxaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67.

Comment: I know this is specialized language, and that we would like to see more context about where this quote actually came from, but I don't think it should be closed. It's answerable, so if you object to the lack of context, it might be better to down vote instead of close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The page that Damkerng T. linked to](https://books.google.com/books?id=JWxaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67) basically gives the definition:

> Perhaps the broadest category of creativity research is that of environmental "press," a term first coined by Murray to describe pressures (hence "press") that influence creative people or the creative process.

So it's a very specific jargon term, but it clearly means "pressures that influence creative people or processes".  *[Pressures](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pressure)* in this context means something like

> 1 b :  the constraint of circumstance :  the weight of social or economic imposition

or

> 5 :  the stress or urgency of matters demanding attention